# One OnClickListener for several buttons in an AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am creating an app that simulates rolling different types of dice. All the dice are selected via an AlertDialog full of buttons. I want to use one OnClickListener for six of these buttons but when I try to set that listener, eclipse throws a NullPointerException.

```
    package edu.elon.cs.diceroller;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RollMenuActivity extends Activity {

    private int diceAmount;
    private int diceSides;
    private boolean sum;

    private Button addDiceButton;
    private Button rollDiceButton;
    private ListView diceListView;

    private Button oneButton;
    private Button twoButton;
    private Button threeButton;
    private Button fourButton;
    private Button fiveButton;
    private Button sixButton;

    private Button d4;
    private Button d6;
    private Button d8;
    private Button d12;
    private Button d20;

    private Button sumButton;
    private Button top3Button;
    private Button trimButton;
    private Button avgButton;
    private Button hiLoButton;
    private Button loHiButton;

    private TextView displayQuantity;
    private TextView displayType;
    private TextView displayArrange;

    private OnClickListener addDiceListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View aArg0) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    RollMenuActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater
                    .from(RollMenuActivity.this);
            View layout = factory.inflate(R.layout.dice_select, null);
            alert.setView(layout);


            alert.show();

        }
    };
    private OnClickListener rollDiceListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View aV) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_roll_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private OnClickListener quantityListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button aButton = (Button) v;
            String buttonNumber = aButton.getText().toString();
            diceAmount = Integer.parseInt(buttonNumber.trim());
            displayQuantity.setText(buttonNumber);

        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_roll_menu);

        addDiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adddicebutton);
        rollDiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rolldicebutton);
        diceListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dicelistview);

        addDiceButton.setOnClickListener(addDiceListener);
        rollDiceButton.setOnClickListener(rollDiceListener);

        oneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        twoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        threeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        fourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        fiveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        sixButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

        oneButton.setOnClickListener(quantityListener);
        twoButton.setOnClickListener(quantityListener);
        threeButton.setOnClickListener(quantityListener);
        fourButton.setOnClickListener(quantityListener);
        fiveButton.setOnClickListener(quantityListener);
        sixButton.setOnClickListener(quantityListener);


        displayQuantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayquantity);

    }
}


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RollMenuActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dicelistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adddicebutton" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rolldicebutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Press or Shake to Roll Dice"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/adddicebutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rolldicebutton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Add a Dice"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/diceselectlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttond4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="d4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonsum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Sum " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttond20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="d20" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonhilo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi-Lo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Type"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:text="Arrange"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttond6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="d6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttontop3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top 3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttond8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="d8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttontrim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Trim " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttond12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="d12" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonavg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Avg. " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="  " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonlohi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lo-Hi" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayquantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displaytype"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayarrange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you set the onClick listener for your button in alert dialog..?

Comment: Can you show the error you get? At what line does it happen in your code?

Comment: The docs state that findViewById returns null if the id isn't found. My guess is one (or more) of your tags aren't on the AlertDialog. Post your layout.xml and your logcat...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

Comment: @DigCamara His button is null, he need to get it from the inflated view, I don't know exact butto to post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating variables that hold instances of the `OnClickListener` implementation, use classes that implement `OnClickListener` and override the `OnClick` method.

During the `onCreate` assign new instances of the objects to the buttons

It's better practice when working with the Android SDK to instantiate your objects during the `onCreate` rather than relying on the class to instantiate them during its creation.

Edit:  I also fixed the `Integer.parseInteger` method you had.  Those throw an Exception if it can't parse it.

```
// Create Classes that implement OnClickListener

private class OnAddDiceListener implements OnClickListener
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext());

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dice_select, null);

        Builder builder = new Builder(v.getContext());
        builder.setView(layout);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}

private class OnRollDiceListener implements OnClickListener
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

    }
}

private class OnQuantityListener implements OnClickListener
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Button button = (Button) v;

        try
        {
            diceAmount = Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            diceAmount = 0;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        displayQuantity.setText(diceAmount);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_roll_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_roll_menu);

    addDiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adddicebutton);
    rollDiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rolldicebutton);
    diceListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dicelistview);

    // Since this is the onCreate method, instantiate the Listeners for the buttons
    addDiceButton.setOnClickListener(new OnAddDiceListener());
    rollDiceButton.setOnClickListener(new OnRollDiceListener());

    oneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    twoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    threeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    fourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    fiveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    sixButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

    // Instantiate the OnQuantityListener
    oneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnQuantityListener());
    twoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnQuantityListener());
    threeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnQuantityListener());
    fourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnQuantityListener());
    fiveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnQuantityListener());
    sixButton.setOnClickListener(new OnQuantityListener());

    displayQuantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayquantity);
}
```